# SOLR: ordering results alphabetically by field

Tags: solr

SOLR results are normally ordered by "best match" of your search criteria. Is it possible to order the results **alphabetically** by a given SOLR field?

I realize that this is not a typical use case, but here's my motivation. We have quite a lot of code written around SOLR that performs queries based on user searches against the various fields of our data. Most of the time, we want a relevancy ordering (i.e. best matches first).

But one anomalous use-case requires that we return data ordered alphabetically by field. I could perform this query using our SQL database (avoiding SOLR altogether), but I'd have to replicate an awful lot of code that's tailored around consuming SOLR results (facets in particular). I'm hoping to use the same code path, if it's possible to get such an ordering from SOLR.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you just have to set the `sort` parameter to `field-name`

Comment: Ah, so simple. "&sort=field_name+asc" is what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: There is a possibility to add several fields to the sorting even. Just add them comma seperated. this way you could further specify the ordering just like for instance ORDER BY in MySQL